# obout mvc combobox selected Index changed event not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, obout

I have this MVC control 
this is my control

```
@Html.Obout(new Obout.Mvc.ComboBox.ComboBox("Country")
                        {
                            SelectedIndex = 0,
                            ShowSelectedImage = true,                                
                            ClientSideEvents = new ComboBoxClientSideEvents()
                            {
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged = "checkalert"
                            },

                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkalert",
                            ID = "Country1",
                            FolderStyle = "~/Content/Obout/ComboBox/styles/plain",
                            FilterType = Obout.Mvc.ComboBox.ComboBoxFilterType.Contains,
                            Width = 150,
                            Height = 200,
                            MenuWidth = 640
                        })
```

and this is my js  function:

```
function checkalert() {
        debugger;
        alert(" change");
     return '1';
    }
```

I have an error that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkalert is not defined
```

I need a `checkalert()` function triggered when selected index changed

Comment: Why you require that combo box I didn't get you question.

Comment: @LaxmanGite I need to use this combobox control and need to call another function on the index changed  of this combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of obout](https://www.obout.com/mvc-combobox/apiclient/aspnet_apiclient_events.aspx) it says that the function would have two input paramters i.e `sender` and `selectedIndex`, according to that your function definitions should look like:

```
function checkalert(sender, selectedIndex) {
    debugger;
    alert(" change");
 return '1';
}
```

And also if you have script after the razor code in view, then you need to put the JavaScript code on top of view.

You can see the working example with code provided on Obout site [here](https://www.obout.com/mvc-combobox/apiclient/aspnet_apiclient_events.aspx).

and also remove the other `SelectedIndexChanged` event which is defined after the `ClientSideEvents` setter as you need just client side event, that would cause errors as well.

Hope it helps you resolve your issue.

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: 'checkalert' is undefined also

Comment: where have you defined the js function?

Comment: on the same view on script tag

Comment: the error comes on pageload or when you change index?

Comment: place the script on top of view before the razor code